# "Process terminated with status -1073741819" simple program with vector

Tags: c++, vector, compiler-errors, codeblocks

for some reason I get the "Process terminated with status -1073741819" error whenever I run my program, I've read that some people get this error because of something wrong with code-blocks/the compiler, i just wanted to know if there is anything wrong with my code before i go reinstalling compilers and such. I'm using code::blocks and the GNU GCC compiler.

my code creates a vector which stores 40 working hours in a week, and a vector inside that vector which stores letters representing the 5 people available in those hours.

**Schedule.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Schedule.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/// Creates a Vector which holds 40 items (each hour in the week)
/// each item has 5 values ( J A P M K or X, will intialize as J A P M K)

vector< vector<string> > week(40, vector<string> (5));

Schedule::Schedule(){
        for (int i = 0; i<40; i++){
            week[i][0] = 'J';
            week[i][1] = 'A';
            week[i][2] = 'P';
            week[i][3] = 'M';
            week[i][4] = 'K';
        }
        // test 
        cout << week[1][3] << endl;
    }
```

**header file:**

```
#ifndef SCHEDULE_H
#define SCHEDULE_H
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Schedule
{
    public:
        Schedule();
    protected:
    private:
        vector< vector<string> > week;

};

#endif // SCHEDULE_H
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Schedule.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Schedule theWeek;
}
```

Comment: Use GDB and run it, then use backtrace.

Comment: `vector< vector<string> > week(40, vector<string> (5));` - This creates a global matrix variable called week (not to be confused with `Schedule::week`). Is this intentional? I assume you want to initialize the member variable in the constructor; If so, you should either write `this->week` in the constructor, or remove/rename the global variable declaration, or place the global declaration within a namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a copiler bug.

You are getting a memory fault in your constructor.

There are several things wrong with your code, for example in your cpp you declare a global vector week which then is hiden in the constructor since the constructor will access Schedule::week .

Your cpp should be something like :

```
// comment out the global declaration of a vector week ...
// you want a vector for each object instantiation, not a shared vector between all Schedule objects
// vector< vector<string> > week(40, vector<string> (5)); 


Schedule::Schedule()
{
    for (int i=0;i<40;i++)
    {
        vector<string> stringValues;
        stringValues.push_back("J");
        stringValues.push_back("A");
        stringValues.push_back("P");
        stringValues.push_back("M");
        stringValues.push_back("K");
        week.push_back(stringValues);
    }
}
```

You get the memory fault in your code when you try to access your week vector for the first time :

```
 week[i][0] = 'J' ;
```

At the moment you call that line of code, your Schedule::week vector has 0 elements inside it (so week[i] is already a fault).